How does Zero-Knowledge Proofs guarantees Integrity?
How does Zero-Knowledge Proofs guarantees Integrity ?
I have understood that ZKPs guarantees confidentiality by the fact that no data is shared but simply the fact the declaration made by the prover is true. But I don't quit get how Integrity gets involved ? Is it simply because no additonnal data is shared then there is no possibility of this additonnal data being altered or compromised ?

Let's say prover claims he know how to factorize 15 into 2 factors. The trusted setup builds a circuit which multiplies 2 numbers. The prover feeds two numbers into the circuit - the verifier checks if output is 15. If yes, then the claim is proved with zero knowledge

I won't say that ZKPs can guarantee confidentiality and integrity, as they have well-defined definitions (semantic-security, INT-CTXT etc).
ZKP guarantees zero-knowledge as it proves some statements without revealing extra information about a certain relation; and completeness/correctness (which is what you call integrity) because of some mathematical properties.
These properties can vary from scheme to scheme, from my experiences they cannot be generalized, that is why proofs of ZKPs are very different from each other.
